# Ubuntu 21.10 dual boot with windows can't connect to my router on wifi, works with phone hotspot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, network-manager

I have installed Ubuntu 21.10 on dual boot, wifi works perfectly on windows.

- Kernel is 5.13, got it after running dist-upgrade
- I can see wifi networks and I can connect to my phone hotspot

When I try to connect to my router network, after a while I get the message "activation of network connection failed"

I saw a comment on reddit saying that since mac address is the same, and I previously connected on windows, there is an issue on ipv6 and removing the device from router setting should solve the problem. Unfortunately my router does not have that option.

I tried changing mac address on Ubuntu with macchanger with no effects, any clue?

Laptop  is  a Lenovo  Thinkpad l15 gen 2, wifi adapter is a realtek  8852

Edit: resetting the router does not solve the issue, the problem could be elsewhere

Comment: Could you elaborate on “ changing mac address on Ubuntu with macchanger with no effects”? Was the MAC address actually changed or has it remained the same? 

Comment: Have you rebooted the router?

Comment: @matigo the MAC was correctly changed as it appears the new one from ifconfig and also from the network manager UI

Comment: @heynnema I will do it tomorrow, left that as a last resort since today I could not

Comment: That should always be the first resort :)

Comment: @ChanganAuto to my surprise, resetting the router lead to the same result, I am lost here

Comment: Would it be an option to disable IPv6 in Linux and/or Windows for that specific connection? Not sure why it could be an issue, but maybe it even is sufficient that you untick an option "Require IPv6 addressing for this connection to complete" in the NetworkManager IPv6 Settings for the connection.

Comment: @cyberbrain oh i forgot to put it in the post, I already tried that. Moreover, resetting the router and logging on linux does not work either, I think this is not a mac collision issue then

Comment: you can try to get more details about the error with `sudo dmesg` which shows kernel errors, or view /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/dmesg (both probably need root rights to view)

Comment: @cyberbrain I did that, the info that I got from dmesg are "send auth to xx:xx: .... xx try 1/3" three times, until 3/3, and then "authentication timed out"

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on the question:
The WiFi auth system config between windows and Linux are different for that one network.

Steps I would try:

1. Note down all details for the windows auth (type: WPA/WPA2/WPA3/something different? PreSharedKey or Enterprise? the actual password?)
2. Remove the WiFi connection from the Ubuntu Network Manager
3. Re-add the WiFi connection with the correct settings that you noted down form the working Windows connection.

Most probably you mis-typed the password, but I bet you already tried to re-enter it correctly. Maybe you have different keyboard mappings in Windows and Linux and so you actually type in different characters by pressing the same keys?

Comment: I tried all of that and I triple (even more) checked the password. I even created a totally unsafe open connection without any authentication required. Same results :(